# Found nil from dateFromString when converting string to date

Tags: ios, swift

Here is my code:

```
 let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter() 
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM, yyyy" 
 let myDate  = dateFormatter.dateFromString("2016-06-10") 
 print(myDate)
```

myDate is nil when I print.

Comment: `"dd MMM, yyyy"` is not the same as `"2016-06-10"`. Use the right format and it will work...

Comment: `dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to convert this "2016-06-10" in to "dd MM, yyyy" then you need to write it like below code,

```
    let dateString = "2016-06-10"
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let date = formatter.dateFromString(dateString)
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM, yyyy"
    let st = formatter.stringFromDate(date!)
    print(st) //output : 10 Jun, 2016
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark it correct so other can use it again.